# extraer una columna de datos de sap y copiar en excel

Tags: excel, sap

buen dia necesito el script para copiar solola columna seleccionada de sap de datos y que se pegue en Excel.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara y no esta bien redactado a lo que quieres.

Comment: quiero copiar esa columna de datos que esta en la imagen de sap y pegar en un excel

Comment: un script que copie y pege la seleccion de datos